# error 150 creating table with mysql with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, mysql-error-150

I'm not really sure why i'm getting error 150 from phpmyadmin in my web-server, when i create the tables in local it works fine, maybe I'm missing something.

Here's my code:

Table usuarios

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'LLave primaria de la tabla' ,
`nombre` VARCHAR(100) NULL COMMENT 'Nombre completo del usuario' ,
`email` VARCHAR(75) NULL COMMENT 'Login del usuario' ,
`password` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT 'Clave del usuario' ,
`fecha_registro` DATETIME NULL COMMENT 'Fecha en la que se registro el usuario' ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Table perfiles:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `perfiles` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'llave primaria de la tabla' ,
`nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT 'Descripción del perfil' ,
`fecha_registro` DATETIME NULL COMMENT 'fecha de registro' ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Table usuarios_perfiles:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios_perfiles` (
`usuario_id` INT NOT NULL ,
`perfil_id` INT NOT NULL ,
INDEX `fk_usuarios_perfiles_usuarios_idx` (`usuario_id` ASC) ,
INDEX `fk_usuarios_perfiles_perfiles1_idx` (`perfil_id` ASC) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_usuarios_perfiles_usuarios`
FOREIGN KEY (`usuario_id` )
REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_usuarios_perfiles_perfiles1`
FOREIGN KEY (`perfil_id` )
REFERENCES `perfiles` (`id` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

When i'm running all this code in my local server it works fine, but when i want to create this in phpmyadmin from my web-server it send error 105.

Comment: This works just fine on my local server (`mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.23-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`). Can you share your exact error's text please?

Comment: It send me this : #1005 - Can't create table 'database.usuarios_perfiles' (errno: 150)

Comment: Also works on sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/617e19

Comment: run `show engine innodb status` and view any errors that are spewed out

Comment: When i create the usuarios table i didn't put the last line ENGINE = InnoDB; and i was getting MyISAM ENGINE, i just change it to ENGINE INNODB and now it everything ok... Thanks all

Comment: Can you please do a self-answer below so we can upvote it?

Comment: Sorry! I didn't close this! The solution was the ENGINE INNODB, When i create the usuarios table i didn't put the last line ENGINE = InnoDB; and i was getting MyISAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was adding the ENGINE INNODB, When i create the usuarios table i didn't put the last line ENGINE = InnoDB; and i was getting MyISAM.

It seems like MyISAM don't let me use fk. When i change the ENGINE to InnoDB everything start to run properly.

Thanks all!